# Scroll background image on the body on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want an image on the body of the website, for which I am using this CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center top; 
}
```

When I resize the browser I wish to see the scrollbar appearing so that image can be scrolled. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to put your image with `img` tag.

Comment: @ROX without img tag is it not possible? I have seen some website doing that. check out this theactsoftheapostles.com

Comment: @EldhoAbraham - `min-height`/`min-width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `min-width` and `min-height` for your `body` based on width and height of your image:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url(http://theactsoftheapostles.com/images/yesu-ki-jai-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center top; 
    min-width: 1390px;
    min-height: 903px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fbfq8sft/2/).

---

*However I think it's better to avoid using horizontal scrollbar.*

Comment: thanks!! that works..
However I wish to set the min width and height using JS

`$(body).css({'min-width': window.screen.availWidth, 'min-height': window.screen.availHeight});`

not able to achieve in this case.

Comment: basically for the monitors greater than 1390px width, the image won't be full, then i have to use `background-size: cover;` to get it full, and then the scroll won't come as the image will get resized on resizing the browser